# How to serve a Flutter web app with Django?

Tags: python, django, flutter, flutter-web

After building a flutter web app with

```
flutter build web
```

I want to serve the app using a simple Django server.
How can I do that?

Comment: https://dev.to/amartyadev/flutter-app-authentication-with-django-backend-1-21cp

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After running the command, copy the `build\web` directory from the flutter project to your django project. Let's say you put it at the root and renamed it to `flutter_web_app`.

So we have,

```
djangoproject
  | djangoproject
       | settings.py
       | urls.py
       | ...
  | flutter_web_app
  | ... 
  | other apps
```

Now edit the `base` tag in `flutter_web_app/index.html` to give the application a prefix. Note that the prefix/base should start and end with a `/`.

```html
<head>
...

    <base href="/flutter_web_app/">

...
</head>
```

Now, in your `djangoproject/urls.py`, match the prefix and serve your flutter application.

```py
from django.urls import path
from django.views.static import serve
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
FLUTTER_WEB_APP = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'flutter_web_app')

def flutter_redirect(request, resource):
    return serve(request, resource, FLUTTER_WEB_APP)

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('flutter_web_app/', lambda r: flutter_redirect(r, 'index.html')),
    path('flutter_web_app/<path:resource>', flutter_redirect),
]
```

Running this locally, url `127.0.0.1/flutter_web_app` will serve our `flutter_web_app/index.html`.

All the files required by the flutter application are prefixed with `flutter_web_app`. For eg. `main.dart.js` is requested with a GET to `flutter_web_app/main.dart.js`. We extract the path after the prefix as `resource` and serve the corresponding file from `flutter_web_app` directory (`flutter_redirect` function).

Comment: how to serve from root? I mean I want to place files in flutter_web_app but open it directly from example.com not example.com/flutter_web_app?

Comment: Use href="/" and match the path in url patterns

Comment: I'm getting _flutter is not defined error. Did exactly as you said. django is serving the flutter.js file as well.
 
The error in console says:

1. Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/flutter_web/flutter.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

2. Uncaught ReferenceError: _flutter is not defined
    at (index):46:7