# Flutter Web Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: django, flutter-web

I'm having problem to deploy my flutter web app to cpanel.
Please find the screenshot of the error

[image]

And this is my current base href on index.html

```
<base href="/">
```

I found some questions asking about this issue but nothing is worked for me.
I follow the solution on this link when deploying the app [How to serve a Flutter web app with Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61582897/how-to-serve-a-flutter-web-app-with-django)

I also tried to change the base href to `<base href="./">` , `<base href="/web_app_name/">` , and also remove the base href but still didn't work.

Hope someone has the solution for this.

Comment: having similar issue. did you got any fix?